# Still behind the origin after git pull

Tags: git

I have a cloned repository which is now behind origin by X commits. `git pull` looks like it works fine, compressing, receiving etc. But when I try `git status` after `git pull` there's a message that I'm still behind. What could be the cause of this problem?

That's a message after `git status` :

```
On branch release/xxxx
Your branch is behind 'origin/release/xxxx' by 351 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working tree clean`
```

Comment: Can you add the "behind message" and also commands that you tried into OP?

Comment: Used just to commands, pull and status, added status message

Comment: What is the output of `git pull origin release/xxxx`?

Comment: @sajibkhan, just saw your comment. Please post that as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pull with branch name:

```
$ git pull origin release/xxxx
```

Note: you are running **git pull origin/release/xxxx** (give space instead '/' after *origin*)

Comment: Just used slash instead of space by mistake. This certain command works fine

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running simply `git pull`, pull a specific branch:

```
git pull origin release/xxxx
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped

Comment: just saw @sajibkhan's comment above. If he posts that comment as an answer, mark his answer as accepted instead of mine. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I just didn't notice a space instead of slash in his comment

Comment: This helps but it wasn't a permanent fix, i.e. just `git pull` continues to do nothing

Answer (score -2):

just do `git pull origin master` this will pull changes from the origin remote, master branch and merge them to the local checked-out branch.

Comment: a) There was no `master` branch mentioned. b) There are already two answers recommending `git pull origin release/xxxx`. Even if you didn't used the wrong branch name your answer would not be an improvement or provide new details. See [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)